# Animated: `useNativeDriver` was not specified. This is a required option and must be explicitly set to `true` or `false on React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

i have sample code like :

```
import import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import {View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native'; 
import DatePicker from 'react-native-datepicker';
   
    export default class MyDatePicker extends Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props)
    //set value in state for initial date
    this.state = {date:"15-05-2018"}
    }

    render(){
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <DatePicker
          style={{width: 200}}
          date={this.state.date} 
          mode="date" 
          placeholder="select date"
          format="DD-MM-YYYY"
          minDate="01-01-1990"
          maxDate="31-12-2020"
          confirmBtnText="Confirm"
          cancelBtnText="Cancel"
          customStyles={{
            dateIcon: {
              position: 'absolute',
              left: 0,
              top: 4,
              marginLeft: 0
            },
            dateInput: {
              marginLeft: 36
            }
          }}
          onDateChange={(date) => {this.setState({date: date})}}
        />

      </View>
    )
    }
    }
```

Is something wrong here?
The program is working but it showing warn like Animated: `useNativeDriver` was not specified. This is a required option and must be explicitly set to `true` or `false`

Comment: here is my import 
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import DatePicker from 'react-native-datepicker';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your implementation. There is the problem with `react-native-datepicker` itself. You could check the issue here => https://github.com/xgfe/react-native-datepicker/pull/411

For now, ignore the error, wait for the next version of `react-native-datepicker`. The library authors might resolve it.

Or else, you could fork the library itself as do make changes to the file as per the PR given above.